# Replace values outside range with NA using replace_with_na function

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na, data-cleaning

I have the following dataset

```
structure(list(a = c(2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 8), b = c(4, 5, 1, 9, 12, 
NA), c = c(50, 34, 77, 88, 33, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

  a  b  c
1 2  4 50
2 1  5 34
3 9  1 77
4 2  9 88
5 9 12 33
6 8 NA 60
```

From column b I only want values between 4-9. Column c between 50-80. Replacing the values outside the range with NA, resulting in

```
structure(list(a = c(2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 8), b = c(4, 5, NA, 9, NA, 
NA), c = c(50, NA, 77, NA, NA, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

  a  b  c
1 2  4 50
2 1  5 NA
3 9 NA 77
4 2  9 NA
5 9 NA NA
6 8 NA 60
```

I've tried several things with replace_with_na_at function where this seemed most logical:

```
test <- replace_with_na_at(data = test, .vars="c",
                          condition = ~.x < 2 & ~.x > 2)
```

However, nothing I tried works. Does somebody know why? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `replace_with_na_at()` comes from what package? You should include the relevant library call in your reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mention the packages you are using. From googling, i'm guessing you are using `naniar`. The problem appears to be that you did not properly specify the condition, but the following should work:

```r
library(naniar)

test <- structure(list(a = c(2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 8), 
                    b = c(4, 5, 1, 9, 12, NA),
                    c = c(50, 34, 77, 88, 33, 60)), 
               class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c(NA, -6L)) 

replace_with_na_at(test, "c", ~.x < 50 | .x > 80)
#>   a  b  c
#> 1 2  4 50
#> 2 1  5 NA
#> 3 9  1 77
#> 4 2  9 NA
#> 5 9 12 NA
#> 6 8 NA 60
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Yet another base R solution, this time with function `is.na<-`

```
is.na(test$b) <- with(test, b < 4 | b > 9)
is.na(test$c) <- with(test, c < 50 | c > 80)
```

A package `naniar` solution with a pipe could be

```
library(naniar)
library(magrittr)

test %>%
  replace_with_na_at(
    .vars = 'b',
    condition = ~(.x < 4 | .x > 9)
  ) %>%
  replace_with_na_at(
    .vars = 'c',
    condition = ~(.x < 50 | .x > 80)
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply could use `Map` to replace your values with `NA`.

```
dat[2:3] <- Map(function(x, y) {x[!x %in% y] <- NA;x}, dat[2:3], list(4:9, 50:80))
dat
#   a  b  c
# 1 2  4 50
# 2 1  5 NA
# 3 9 NA 77
# 4 2  9 NA
# 5 9 NA NA
# 6 8 NA 60
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(a = c(2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 8), b = c(4, 5, 1, 9, 12, 
NA), c = c(50, 34, 77, 88, 33, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subset with a logical vector testing your conditions.

```
x$b[x$b < 4 | x$b > 9] <- NA
x$c[x$c < 50 | x$c > 80] <- NA
x
#  a  b  c
#1 2  4 50
#2 1  5 NA
#3 9 NA 77
#4 2  9 NA
#5 9 NA NA
#6 8 NA 60
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(a = c(2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 8), b = c(4, 5, 1, 9, 12, 
NA), c = c(50, 34, 77, 88, 33, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df1[c('b', 'c')] <- map2(df1 %>% 
       select(b, c), list(c(4, 9), c(50,80)), ~ 
           replace(.x, .x < .y[1]|.x > .y[2], NA))
```